# Renaming Really Deep Remote Git Commit Message

Tags: git, github

What is the best way to rename a remote git commit message that is really deep? I have a commit message that is 70+ messages deep and I need to rename it because it has some mistakes in the message.

I've researched `git rebase -i HEAD~` but that seems crazy with how deep the commit actually is. Is that the proper way to handle this or is there a better way that I've been unable to find so far?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The command you've researched is the way this is done. Changing a commit message 70+ commits back is rewriting history; it's a powerful change.

From the docs:

> To modify a commit that is farther back in your history, you must move to more complex tools. Git doesn’t have a modify-history tool, but you can use the rebase tool to rebase a series of commits onto the HEAD they were originally based on instead of moving them to another one. With the interactive rebase tool, you can then stop after each commit you want to modify and change the message, add files, or do whatever you wish.

For your situation, this means some variation on the following:

```sh
$ git rebase -i HEAD~80 // some range including your target commit
```

This will open a Git Rebase TODO. Once there, change `pick` to `reword` on the commit your target commit. Write and quit the buffer, and then an editor will open with the message you'd like to change. Rewrite it and save the buffer.

Now, force push the branch, and the history has been rewritten.

```
$ git push -f
```

[Git Tools - Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to place a commit with the very same changes,
but with the message you want anywhere behind the commit to be renamed
(the original is keps but identical one is inserted behind with right message)

The strategy is as follows:

1. Copy `yourWorkingBranchName`
2. git checkout commitIdFromTheOneBehindTheBadOne
3. git checkout -b tempBranchToRenameCommit
4. reset --soft HEAD~1
5. git add -A
6. git commit -m "corrected message"
7. git merge `yourWorkingBranchName`
8. Now you have in the tempBranchToRenameCommit
   the previously mentioned logic, if you want to check
   (and also verify that same files were touched
   if you include --name-status, otherwise omit):
9. git log --oneline --name-status

It will eventually display

```
commitIdFromTheOneAfterTheBadOne commitMessageFromTheOneAfterTheBadOne
<files changes 3>
commitIdFromTheBadOne commitMessageFromTheBadOne
<files changes 2>
commitIdFromTheOneYouJustRewrote commitMessageFromTheOneYouJustRewrote
<files changes 2>
commitIdFromTheOneBehindTheBadOne commitMessageFromTheOneBehindTheBadOne
<files changes 1>
```